# which one is correct, "Master's student" or "Masters student" or "MSc student"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrase-requests, questions

I don't know exactly which one is more official and correct?
Master's Student
Masters Student
MSc Student

What is main difference?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, as using *master's* with *degree* arguably works differently from using it with *student*. A master's degree is a degree that belongs to a master, which makes it natural to include an apostrophe. A person studying to become a master, however, does not belong to a master, which makes the apostrophe in *master's student* questionable. Taken literally, a master's student would be somebody who is studying with a master, which is clearly not what is intended.

Answer (score 21):

There are various master's degrees, such as MA (Master of Arts), MSc (Master of Science), MPhil (Master of Philosophy), MTheol (Master of Theology).

"An MSc student" would only cover one of these possibilities, while "a master's student" would cover all of them.  You could say "a postgraduate student", but this would include people studying towards doctorates.

The apostrophe in "master's" should be retained (see https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/master_1 for examples).

"Master's student" has some official or semi-official usage ( https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22master%27s+students%22+site:.ac.uk ; http://www.manchester.ac.uk/study/masters/funding/living-costs/ ).

Comment: Someone proposed an edit, which I rejected as unnecessarily radical.  However, I accept that most style guides recommed a lower-case for generic references to a "master's" (whereas specific degrees are capitalised), so I have amended the casing accordingly.